# Using DbContext outside of the project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to MVC, and whilst I'm comfortable in most of the things I do, I have two separate MVC projects in different solutions and I now need the second one to communicate with the db backing the first one for some new functionality I'm building.

I have sometimes accessed this database referencing the ApplicationDbContext class from other projects in my solution like so:

```
context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PortalConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

This works fine in other projects within my current solution but when I reference the ApplicationDbContext class in my second MVC site (outside of my solution) I cannot define the connection string like I have above..the database settings are not accessible (I need the connection string to change in Debug vs. Release versions so I do need to define the connection string.). I assume this is because it's not in the same solution so I cannot set the original MVC project as a pre-requisite in the build order.

How can I ensure the new context object I create within my second solution uses the correct connection string at run time?

JK

Comment: Are they under the same solution ? If so you can create another project that will handle all the DAL.

Comment: No they aren't under the same solution. That's my problem atm. It's weird that I can't access the ApplicationDbContext's database settings from within my other solution, I have done that within the same solution absolutely fine.

Comment: It is wrong. You should create a DAL for each project and just communicate from one to another project.

Comment: @Kram The DbContext represents a database; if it is in fact the same database both apps will be using, creating a second copy of the DAL project is a huge waste of time.  Better to reference it and realize you need to update both apps if the schema changes.

Comment: When referencing is from my second solution however I cannot specify the connection string in the same way written in my question....due to my inexperience I'm not sure if the Debug/Release transforms will work properly when project 1 isn't built as a dependancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from not knowing where the connection string should come from. A connection string is a dependency that is supplied by the running assembly. Both MVC projects have their own web.config files, both of which should have the connection string to your database. The second project can't use the first project's connection string.

Having said that, if you use exactly the same data layer in two applications (no matter what type of application) you better make a separate assembly containing the `DbContext` and classes and mappings. Again, the connection string that's used during runtime is not in this project, but in each separate application's config file that uses the data layer.

By default a `DbContext` will look for a connection string having its name. So if your context is `ApplicationDbContext`, use a named connection string like

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand. I have the connection string in my second solution, however my usual way of ensuring this be the connection string that is used (as in my question) won't work in my second solution. i was unaware of the naming convention. My context class uses DefaultConnection as the connection string from app settings so I will name it that so it can find it. Sorry for my lack of knowledge on my own solutions, I inherited this a while back so some stones are still unturned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few options:

1-Change your controllers to an ApiController and consume your data through a webapi;

2-Move your mappings to a class library, and just add this class library to both solutions: mvc app and the other project.

Comment: In 2- you're referring to placing ApplicationDbContext within a different project? Would that aid my accessing it outside the solution? The ApiController point is a good one as it's flexible and wouldn't be too much trouble, but it would be preferable to be able to extend solution 2's functionality without having to modify solution 1's ApiController so often. It's likely solution 2's communications with the Db will be quite changeable and be extended often.

Comment: Yes, you'll just need to share the connection string in both solutions.

Comment: The second option is way easier to maintain, assuming both apps can follow the same release schedule.  And if they don't, its probably better that they do, as building a web service just to expose your data (which is a bad idea anyway; build a server that exposes business use cases, not a thin wrapper around the db) is way more expensive.

Comment: So the solution you guys think IS to reference from the second solution? Just with each Release build I will need to Rebuild the first solution also. I'm still confused about the connection string of the DbContext class within my second solution and how I ensure it uses the correct string for Debug/Release